# Convert coordinates to name from mysql - Python / Angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs, google-maps, coordinates

Can someone help to get the the name/address of my coordinates?. I already have these latitude and longitude and the next thing that I wanna do is to convert it. Thank you.

Comment: Given that you already know how to get the data from mysql, you probably want to take a look at the [Google Geocoding API for reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), which is an API that allows for translation of a location on the map into a human-readable address.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the module [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/). Here is example code for finding nearest address to coordinates:

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
>>> location.address
"Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union"
```

Comment: hi I tried to install the geopy but it give me an error : ImportError: No module named geopy.geocoders

Comment: Did you install it using the .whl file?

Comment: Hi I already install it. The next thing I wanna do is to connect this geopy with the query of mysql and then got stuck again. can you help me with this?. Thank you.

Comment: @thinkmind I'm not familiar with mysql. You are trying to query it for an address?

Comment: Try first using individual words in the address or groups of words. Maybe make a list with `address.split(",")` and try using those.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can do something like this. using google geocode services.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.constant("KEYS", {
        "GOOGLE_MAP_KEY": "[YOUR_KEY]"
 })
.service('geoService', function($http, KEYS){ 
    var geocodeUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
    
    this.getLocation = function(lat, lng){
        return $http({
            url: geocodeUrl, 
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                key: KEYS.GOOGLE_MAP_KEY,
                latlng: lat + ',' + lng
            }
        }).then(function(obj){
            return obj.data;
        });
    };
})
.controller('gCntrl', function($scope, geoService){
    $scope.get = function(){
        geoService.getLocation($scope.lat, $scope.lng).then(function(data){
            if(data.results && data.results.length > 0){
                $scope.results = data.results;
            } else {
                $scope.results = "No Results Found";
            }
            
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="gCntrl">
        Lat: <input ng-model="lat" />
        lang: <input ng-model="lng" />
        <button type="button" ng-click="get()">Get Me Location</button>
        <div>
            <span ng-bind="results"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```